# troubles with dictionaries, python

Tags: python, class, methods, dictionary

I'm creating a class to work with .txt files for practice. i'm a little confused about how to implement a certain method in my class. my class is as follows:

```
class Collection_of_word_counts():
'''this class has one instance variable, called counts which stores a dictionary
where the keys are words and the values are their occurences'''

def __init__(self:'Collection_of_words', file_name: str) -> None:
    '''  this initializer will read in the words from the file,
    and store them in self.counts'''
    l_words = open(file_name).read().split()
    s_words = set(l_words)


    self.counts = dict([ [word, l_words.count(word)] 
                        for word 
                        in s_words])
```

now, one of my methods will compare two dictionaries and remove any occurrences in which they both contain the same work or, rather key. this is what i have so far, unfinished, and i'm pretty sure i'm flat out wrong. i would like to guidance as to how to think like a programmer in terms of implementing this method. dictionaries go right over my head. i'm a novice.

```
def compare_coll(self,coll_1, coll_2) -> None:
    '''  compares two collections of key words which are dictionaries, 
    <coll_1> and <coll_2>, and removes from both collections every word 
    that appears in b oth collection'''

    while d1.contains(d2.keys) and d2.contains(d1.keys):
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of input and the output you would expect for those inputs?  They should be very short examples, like: `d1 = {'abc':3, 'abcd':2, 'foo':1}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> now, one of my methods will compare two dictionaries and remove any occurrences in which they both contain the same work or, rather key.

This is really trivial with set operations:

```
def compare_coll(self, coll_1, coll_2):
    # get list of keys which exist in both dicts
    overlap = set(coll_1).intersection(coll_2)
    # delete these keys from both dicts
    for key in overlap:
        del coll_1[key], coll_2[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble with some code, you should always try to leave aside the actual code and think about the algorithm: that is, how it would actually work in pseudo-code or even plain English. In this case, it would be as follows:

```
Go through every key in the first dict.
For each one, does it exist in the second dict?
If so, remove it from both.
```

When put like that, it's not too complicated, so you should be able to code it up.

(By the way, there is a one-line implementation of this using sets. Don't worry about that for now.)

Comment: This has a little difficulty with removing items from a dict while iterating over it.

Comment: Not so. When you iterate over a dictionary's keys, you get a copy, which does not change when you remove items from the dict. See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items).

Comment: Oh yes. I was thinking of iterating over the dictionary itself, which yields the keys. Iterating over `d.keys()` (or `list(d.keys())` in Python 3) should work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def compare_coll(self,coll_1, coll_2)

    set1 = set(coll_1)
    set2 = set(coll_2)
    return set1 - set2
```

here is the output from ipython

In [6]: list1 = ['bar','foo','hello','hi']

In [7]: list2 = ['alpha','bar','hello','xam']

In [8]:

In [8]: set1 = set(list1)

In [9]: set2 = set(list2)

In [10]: set1 - set2
Out[10]: set(['hi', 'foo'])